# Converting a DateTime Object to a specific timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a dateTime string "2019-02-14 17:18:22".
I would like to convert this above-mentioned dateTime string to a specific timezone dateTime .

Here the timezone will be extracted from another dateTime string - "2019-02-14T17:28:24+08:00".

I did look up at the utcOffset function but I don't know how to use the offset value (330 in mycase).

Expected result:   The first String is fairly simple 5:18 PM .
But once getting converted to the specific timezone, it will be 2:48 PM.

Answer (score 0):

Heres how I use timezone offsets.

I get DateTimeIn, which is offset to (UTC+00:00) from the server.

Then to convert to the browser's timezone (UTC-05:00), i use: `getTimezoneOffset()` to update the object to the local timezone.

`var dateObj = new Date(DateTimeIn);
dateObj.setMinutes(dateObj.getMinutes() + dateObj.getTimezoneOffset());`

Without this, my server downloaded datetimes are offset and unusable.